# What does $ \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-1\rangle$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Could someone explain exactly what the following ring structure is: $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]:= \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-1\rangle$ ?

What a typical element of this set looks like ?

What are the equivalence classes $[x], [y]$ of $X$ and $Y$ in the quotient ?

Is there a geometrical link with the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ ?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: please use \mathbb{Z}

Comment: A ring map from $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ to $\mathbb R$ corresponds to a point $(x,y)\in \mathbb R$ in the unit circle. This correspondence is bijective. In other words, the $\mathbb R$-points in $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z[x,y])$ form the unit circle.

Comment: Please choose informative titles like the one I edited yours to be.

Comment: I don't know why you'd write "$\mathbb{Z}[x,y]:= $" in front of that quotient. Most people would recognize $\mathbb Z [x,y]$ as a polynomial ring in two variables, not that quotient.  Perhaps it is a typo?

Comment: @JOSÉMONTENEGRO I think \mathbf{Z} is fine too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think about these as trigonometric polynomials (polynomials in the functions $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$) with integral coefficients.

For an arbitrary commutative ring $A$, there is a unique division with remainder by monic polynomials in $A[x]$.  In particular, taking $A = \mathbf Z[x]$, every $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbf Z[x,y] = \mathbf Z[y][x]$ has the form
$$
f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2 - 1)q(x,y) + r(x,y)
$$
where $r(x,y)$ is $0$ or has $x$-degree at most $2$: $r(x,y) = a(y) + b(y)x$ where $a(y)$ and $b(y)$ are in $\mathbf Z[y]$. Thus
$$
f(x,y) \equiv r(x,y) \equiv a(y) + b(y)x \bmod x^2 + y^2 - 1.
$$
That shows all elements of $\mathbf Z[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ are $\mathbf Z[y]$-linear combinations of $1$ and $x$, and you can check such combinations are unique: if $a(y) + b(y)x \equiv c(y) + d(y)x \bmod x^2 + y^2 - 1$ for some $a(y), b(y), c(y), d(y)$ in $\mathbf Z[y]$, then $a(y) = c(y)$ and $b(y) = d(y)$.

In more concrete terms, using the relation $\cos^2\theta = 1 - \sin^2\theta$ we can write every polynomial in $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ with integral coefficients in exactly one way as $a(\sin \theta) + b(\sin \theta)\cos \theta$ for unique polynomials $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ in $\mathbf Z[t]$.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which lack context.